# Translate curl to node request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, httprequest

I have a curl that looks like this:

```
curl -X "POST" "https://theEndpoint.com" \
-H "Authorization: Basic theEncodedUserName/Password" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d "{\"GETRSDATA_Input\":{\"@xmlns\":\"http://theEndpoint.com\",\"RESTHeader\":{\"@xmlns\":\"http://theEndpoint.com/header\"},\"InputParameters\":{\"P_CHANGESINCE_DATE\":\"0460070398\"}}}"
```

I'm using the [request](https://github.com/request/request#http-authentication)  module in my express app like this:

```
var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://theEndpoint.com',
  headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic theEncodedUserName/Password',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  multipart: [{
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      body: JSON.stringify({"GETRSDATA_Input":{"@xmlns":"http://theEndpoint.com","RESTHeader":{"@xmlns":"http://theEndpoint.com/header"},"InputParameters":{"P_CHANGESINCE_DATE":"0460070398"}}})
}],
```

I have a callback function to handle the response and I run it with:

`request(options, callback);`

Does that look right?  I don't believe I'm setting up the request properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close to being correct but not quite, there are a few things about your request options that need to change.

If you're going to be passing JSON in the request you don't need to set the `Content-Type` header. `request` provides the flag `json` which is a `boolean` value, if `true` then `Content-Type` will be set to `application/json` and the body will be properly stringified, the response will also be properly parsed to JSON.

Additionally, your request body shouldn't be passed in the `multipart` attribute because you're not making a multipart request. You should be using the `body` attribute.

I also see that your request body is already stringified based on what you supplied in the question. You don't need to stringify it beforehand as I stated above `request` will take of that for you.

When doing Basic Auth, you can use the `auth` property on the request. For more info on the `auth` property see the [`request auth docs`](https://github.com/request/request#http-authentication)

```
var reqBody = JSON.parse("{\"GETRSDATA_Input\":{\"@xmlns\":\"http://theEndpoint.com\",\"RESTHeader\":{\"@xmlns\":\"http://theEndpoint.com/header\"},\"InputParameters\":{\"P_CHANGESINCE_DATE\":\"0460070398\"}}}");

var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://theEndpoint.com',
  auth: {
    user: YourUsername,
    password: YourPassword,
    sendImmediately: true
  },
  body: reqBody,
  json: true
};

request(options, function(err, res, body) {
    // If an error occurred return the error.
    if (err) return err;

    // No error occurred return the full reponse
    return res;
});
```